# Getting error when iterating through multiple excel files and trying to write the data in to sql table

Tags: python, sql, excel, file

Good afternoon,

I am trying to get the following block of code to work. The purpose of the code is to do the following steps:

1. Iterate through several files in a given directory.
2. For each file, normaizle the data if no data is present so there are no blank cells.
3. Write the data in to an sql table. (I didn't include the actual sql statements as there were no issues with the actual updates.)

Code:

```
import xlrd
import os
import os.path
import glob
import fnmatch
import pyodbc
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    #xlsfiles=['1128CNLOAD.xlsx']
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('CNLOAD.xlsx') ]
    print (xlsfiles, "print1")
    for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
        book=xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
        sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)
        cell=sheet.cell(1,1)
        print (sheet, "print 2")
        sheet0 = book.sheet_by_index(0)
        values=()        
        print sheet0.nrows
        print sheet.cell(1, 0)
        for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 1) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                 sheet._cell_types[row_index][1] = xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                 sheet._cell_values[row_index][1] = 'DEFAULT'
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 2) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                 sheet._cell_types[row_index][2] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                 sheet._cell_values[row_index][2] = 0.0
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 3) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                 sheet._cell_types[row_index][3] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                 sheet._cell_values[row_index][3] = 0.0
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 4) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                 sheet._cell_types[row_index][4] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                 sheet._cell_values[row_index][4] = 0.0
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 5) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                 sheet._cell_types[row_index][5] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                 sheet._cell_values[row_index][5] = 0.0
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 6) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                 sheet._cell_types[row_index][6] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                 sheet._cell_values[row_index][6] = 0.0
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 7) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                 sheet._cell_types[row_index][7] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                 sheet._cell_values[row_index][7] = 0.0
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 8) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                sheet._cell_types[row_index][8] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                sheet._cell_values[row_index][8] = 0.0
            if sheet.cell_type(row_index, 9) == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY:
                sheet._cell_types[row_index][9] = xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER
                sheet._cell_values[row_index][9] = 0.0
            print sheet.row(row_index)
            row_num         = row_index
            secsym          = str(sheet.cell(row_index,0).value.upper())
            pvsym           = str(sheet.cell(row_index,1).value.upper())
            min_bid_off     = float(sheet.cell(row_index,2).value)
            min_ask_off     = float(sheet.cell(row_index,3).value)
            min_bid_offpt   = float(sheet.cell(row_index,4).value)
            min_ask_offpt   = float(sheet.cell(row_index,5).value)
            max_bid_off     = float(sheet.cell(row_index,6).value)
            max_ask_off     = float(sheet.cell(row_index,7).value)
            max_bid_offpt   = float(sheet.cell(row_index,8).value)
            max_ask_offpt   = float(sheet.cell(row_index,9).value)
            values = (secsym,pvsym,min_bid_off,min_bid_offpt,min_ask_off,min_ask_offpt,max_bid_off,max_bid_offpt,max_ask_off,max_ask_offpt)
            print(values)
            cursor.execute(update_dyna,values)  
            cnxn.commit()
```

When I run this block of code, it seems that the first iteration works but on the second, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Python\Python 2.7 Scripts\Src\ExcelLoop.py", line 92, in <module>
    cursor.execute(update_dyna,values)  
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Sybase Wire Protocol driver]Data type for parameter 2 has changed since first SQLExecute call. (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

The data contains security symbol data for 2 exchanges. If I isolate the data to 1 exchange, the above script works. When the update contains both exchanges, the code doesn't work.

Here is an example of the data:

ABCDEF  ALLL3_BZ    0.05    0.05    0   0   0   0   6   6

BCDEFG  EFR_CN  0.003   0.003   0   0   0.10    0.10    0   0

Here is a different set of code to do the same kind of update that works. My friend that wrote the code and I don't know why one would work vs. the version above. Any help with understanding where the issue is would be helpful, ty again.

```
columns =     ['secsym','pvsym','min_bid_off','min_bid_off_pt','min_ask_off','min_ask_off_pt','max_bid_off','max_bi    d_off_pt','max_ask_off','max_ask_off_pt']
tableName = "cm_dyna"
for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):

    values = []
    row_num         = row_index
    for i in range(2):
        values.append("'" + sheet.cell(row_index,i).value.encode('ascii','ignore').rstrip().upper() + "'")
    for i in range(2,sheet.ncols):
        values.append(float(sheet.cell(row_index,i).value))
    print values  

    query = "insert into " + tableName + "(" + ",".join(columns) + ") values("
    query += ",".join([str(x) for x in values]) + ")"
    print query
    cursor.execute(query)
    cnxn.commit()
```

Comment: Do you have headers in your XLS file, and, if so, are you dealing with them correctly?

Comment: I do, and I thought with the way that I structured the loop, I was bypassing that row from trying to be written to the SQL.

Comment: I found the issue, the data that I have in column b in excel has data of different lengths. So for rows 1 and 2, the data is 6 characters long. For row 3, the data is 7 characters long and when the update hits that row, that is when the error is triggered. If I make the data in column b 6 characters long and run the script, everything is processed correctly. Anyone know why this would be the case?

Comment: What kind of database are you using, and what datatype is the column that B is mapped to?

Comment: sybase and column b is a character type.

Comment: sybase and column b is a character type. In addition, the data I am using represents stock symbols from 2 exchanges. If I keep the lists independent by exchange, the update works. If I combine the lists from 2 exchanges, this is when the issue appears. I will add an example of the data for the 2 exchanges. Thank you again for any help.

Comment: quick update, a friend was able to come up with a different version of the sybase updaet that works when iterating through the excel file. Neither of us though havce any idea why this version of the code works instead of the version that I wrote. I am sharing the working code above and if anyone has any insight, we are just curious why one would work vs. the other.

Comment: My guess would be that the error has something to do with the character encoding, and that `.encode('ascii','ignore')` in the new code fixed it.